# RegEx to remove new line characters and replace with comma

Tags: ruby, regex, arrays

I scraped a website using Nokogiri and after using xpath I was left with the following string (which is a few td's pushed into one string).

```
"Total First Downs\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t359\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t274\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"
```

My goal is to make this into an array that looks like the following(it will be a nested array):

```
["Total First Downs", "359", "274"]
```

The issue is creating a regex equation that removes the escaped characters, subs in one "," but does not sub in a "," after the last set of integers. If the comma after the last set of integers is necessary, I could use #compact to get rid of the nil that occurs in the array. If you need the code on how I scraped the website here it is: (please note i saved the webpage for testing in order for my ip address to not get burned during the trial phase)

```
f = File.open('page')
doc = Nokogiri::HTML:(f)
f.close

number = doc.xpath('//tr[@class="tbdy1"]').count

stats = Array.new(number) {Array.new}
i = 0

doc.xpath('//tr[@class="tbdy1"]').each do |tr|
  stats[i] << tr.text
  i += 1
end
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't fully understand your problem, but the result can be easily achieved with this:

```
"Total First Downs\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t359\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t274\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"
.split(/[\n\t]+/)
# => ["Total First Downs", "359", "274"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `gsub`

```
"Total First Downs\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t359\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t274\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t".gsub("/[\n\t]+/",",")
```